# Hatch with Shading

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, gradient

I would like to have a rectangle that has some hatch. Furthermore, the hatch should have some shading. But, I am only able to get a transition of the colors in the background. Does anyone know how to only have a color gradient in the hatch with only a white background?

Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\fill[left color=blue!40, right color=white, postaction={pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue!40}] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393131/31034

Comment: Thank you. I have found this as well. But was not able to adapt it to a north west pattern and defining the dimensions in the tikz environment...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only for fun!

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{3}
\def\lw{0.2}
\draw[blue, thick] (0,0) rectangle (\a,\a);
\foreach \x [count=\i] in{0,0.1,0.2,...,\a}{
\draw [blue,line width=\lw mm,opacity=\i/45](\x,0)--(0,\x) (\a,\a-\x)--(\a-\x,\a);}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is conceptually the same as [Ignasi's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/393131/121799) in that the pattern is in the background color, so it determines what should be left unshaded. And in order to customize the pattern I use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60234/121799). And of course you need to dial a `shading angle` to make the shading follow the north east lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
% defining the new dimensions and parameters
\newlength{\hatchspread}
\newlength{\hatchthickness}
\newlength{\hatchshift}
\newcommand{\hatchcolor}{}
% declaring the keys in tikz
\tikzset{hatchspread/.code={\setlength{\hatchspread}{#1}},
         hatchthickness/.code={\setlength{\hatchthickness}{#1}},
         hatchshift/.code={\setlength{\hatchshift}{#1}},% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor/.code={\renewcommand{\hatchcolor}{#1}}}
% setting the default values
\tikzset{hatchspread=3pt,
         hatchthickness=0.4pt,
         hatchshift=0pt,% must be >= 0
         hatchcolor=black}
% declaring the pattern
\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchspread,\hatchthickness,\hatchshift,\hatchcolor]% variables
   {custom north west lines}% name
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr-2\hatchthickness}}% lower left corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr\hatchspread+2\hatchthickness}}% upper right corner
   {\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread}{\dimexpr\hatchspread}}% tile size
   {% shape description
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{-1.5\hatchthickness}{\dimexpr1.5\hatchthickness+\hatchspread+\hatchshift}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr\hatchspread+1pt+\hatchshift}{-1pt}}
    \ifdim \hatchshift > 0pt
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\hatchshift}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\dimexpr1pt+\hatchshift}{-1pt}}
    \fi
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\hatchcolor}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
   }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\fill[left color=blue!40, right color=white,shading angle=45,line width=2pt,
postaction={pattern=custom north west lines, 
hatchthickness=1pt,hatchcolor=white}] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the lines should extend beyond the bounds of the shape.

Comment: @azetina There are always viewer issues with these patterns. In order to address your comment I (i) changed the code slightly and (ii) took the screen shot from acroread.